SSH tunnel proxy disconnect error bad packet length
I am using below command to connect to SSH server on my remote device using AWS Greengrass secure tunnel proxy method
ssh -p 5555 user@localhost

which works perfectly I can manage my device, my remote device is serving a web app (Django + Nginx (React app)), which i proxied to access in my local PC using following command
ssh -p 5555 -v -N -L 8080:localhost:80 user@localhost

Above command do not open interactive shell instead only proxy the remote app to my PC, the problem is when I use curl to check if proxy is working or not e.g. by running
curl http://localhost:8080

I can view the HTML code of REACT app, but when I type the same URL in a browser while loading the connection broke suddenly with following error message
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to localhost ([::1]:5555).
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:8080 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:80
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 8080.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 80 requested.
debug1: channel 2: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 80 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 80 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 80 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 80 requested.
debug1: channel 6: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 80 requested.
debug1: channel 7: new [direct-tcpip]
Bad packet length 1740086933.
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to ::1 port 5555: Connection corrupted

How I can get rid of this problem?
